# Git rebase with a selection of current branch's commits

Tags: git

I want to clean up my git commit on a branch, named *theme*, but with my last rebase from master, I messed up on the git commits log (it's out of order). Here's an example of my current situation and what I'm trying to do:

In my *theme* branch, I have commits ranging from J1-Z1 (hashes)
In my *master* branch, I have commits from A-Z

I want to clean up my *theme* branch commits so that I have all of master's commit (A-Z) along with a group of *theme* branch commits (lets say M1-Z1) ontop, so it would look like A-Z,M1-Z1. That means any other commits before M1 would be discarded.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: That is a rebase `--onto` where you get to say which part of `theme` gets rebased.

Comment: @matt I tried that but I'm not sure I'm doing it right, but when I do ```rebase --onto master M1 Z1``` and check the log, the commits still a mess.

Comment: Unclear what "the commits still a mess" means. Note that you cannot _move_ commits; you will get _new_ commits that copy the old ones. But you have said not what else you desire / expect. If you are thinking that M1 or whatever you start with will magically acquire everything that happened in J1-L1 too, you're wrong about that.

Comment: @matt What I was expecting is a commit log being consisting of master's log with M1-Z1 commits ontop of it. Is that not possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and rebase gives you that. Were  you hoping that this sequence, master followed by some of theme, would be accessible as master or as theme?

Comment: @matt I was hoping it would be belonging to theme

Comment: And at what commit did theme diverge from master?

Comment: @matt What I see is that it has A-Z,M1-Z1 like I wanted, but then it has older commits ontop of that and then M1-Z1 again  (with different hashes). Additionally, the A-Z commits has different hashes than the one from master branch

Comment: Interactive rebase `git rebase -i master` is quite handy in such situations, but it may look quite scary at first contact. When edit with commit list is shown up, just replace `pick` with `skip` (one letter `s` is enough), for commits you want to drop.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making a new branch from master and cherry-picking the selection of commits from theme branch.